# How do I add a custom unsubscribe link to Mailbluster?

Tags: list-unsubscribe

The Mailbluster default unsubscribe link is infected with Andromeda and I have to replace it somehow. It seems to me this will require me to build something that uses the Mailbluster API to take the unsubscribe action within the context of the Mailbluster app. Can anyone suggest an alternative?